# MongoDB: How can I optimize this query?

Tags: java, mongodb, optimization

I want to run a query in MongoDB that return distinct documnets of a collection that include **at least one of the element of an array of strings**. For example if I have a list that include A,B,C, the query should return all distinct documents that include "A" OR "B" OR "C". I have written this query:

```
BasicDBList orList = new BasicDBList();
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("A", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("B", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("C", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));

BasicDBObject or = new BasicDBObject("$or", orList);

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject obj = cursor.next();
            map.put(Integer.parseInt(obj.get("id").toString()),obj.toMap());
        }
```

In the while loop, all fetched documents will be copied into a map for further processing. **But this query is very time consuming and is not scalable. How can I optimize that?**

The Structure of my documents are in the form of

```
{_id:objectid,
 "id":intValue, 
"keyword1":FloatValue,
"keyword2":FloatValue,
"keyword3":FloatValue,
...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating partial index ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#create-a-partial-index and read this too https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes. So you may need to create a parse index for each of the field in your query and run explain to verify indexes are used.

Comment: No, Unfortunately I am not very familiar with index in MongoDB. I update my question with structure of the documents. So, How can I use index with this?

Comment: I read what you suggested but It seems that in this case using of partial index is not possible, because the elements of the list are different in each query. For example in one query A,B,C and in another D,E,F.